# Ruby gem with native extensions not working on AWS Lambda

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rubygems

I have a ruby script that I am trying to run on AWS Lambda.  How do I get this to use a Ruby gem with native extensions?

I have installed my Ruby gems through `bundle install --deployment` and included them in my deployment.  When I run the function on lambda, I get the error:

> Ignoring oj-2.18.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine oj --version 2.18.5
>
> Init error when loading handler
>
> {
>
> "errorMessage": "libruby.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/oj-2.18.5/lib/oj/oj.so",
>
> ...

I have tried including dependencies both in the lambda code itself and as a lambda layer.  The only thing that changes is the path in the error message.

Lambda is able to find my ruby gems.  I get a different error when they are in the wrong location.

`/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/oj-2.18.5/lib/oj/oj.so` does exist.

I have tried this with files generated by `bundle install` on both Ubuntu and AWS-linux.  On both systems, bundle informs me that it is "Installing oj 2.18.5 with native extensions".

If I upload a copy of `libruby.so` to my lambda, and set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to its location and using the set of dependencies installed on the AWS-linux fixes the error listed above, but only to give me an error even more opaque:

> /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /opt/ruby/lib/libruby.so.2.5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running `ldd` on gems/oj-2.18.5/lib/oj/oj.so clarifies the first error.  the problem is not that `oj.so` does not exist, but that `libruby.so.2.5` does not exist.  The second problem is that the current Ruby lambda has glibc version 2.17, where AWS-linux comes with glibc version 2.25.

The fundamental problem here is that you need to install your gems on a system identical to the one they will run on if you have native dependencies.  The best way I've found to do this is using docker.  https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda has docker images of lambda installs.

For ruby, do the following:

1. Build the docker ruby image
2. Copy your gemfile into a pristine directory
3. From that directory, run: `docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task --entrypoint bundle lambci/lambda-base:ruby2.5 install --path=/var/task`

This will give you a folder called `ruby` with a version dependencies compatible with lambda.

If you are planning to use this output with lambda layers, keep in mind that the file structure produced by bunlde is `ruby/2.5.0/...` and it needs need to be `ruby/gems/2.5.0/...` before you upload it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is precisely as you stated, to summarize it: **native extension gems need to be built in the same environment as they will be run**. Therefore, before uploading the vendor to aws, we must install the gems in an environment which is similar to that of lambda.

---

To build your vendor/bundle in a way compliant with lambda, use the following docker container:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.7 bundle install --deployment
```

This will give you a working vendor/bundle dependency.

You can run another container to check if the function works:

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/var/task:ro,delegated lambci/lambda:ruby2.7 lambda_handler.lambda_handler
```

> The full list of images is here:
> https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

The question's already 1 year old but I had to search for about 2 hours to solve the exact same problem with the gem nokogiri, so I thought this might be useful to somebody.

Hope this spares you from some googling hours!