# SQLite in an AWS Lambda Ruby function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am attempting to use SQLite within an AWS Lambda Ruby function, but having trouble with the `sqlite3` gem. Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

---

I have a simple Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "activerecord", "~> 7.0"

gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"
```

After a few false starts trying to run the function on Lambda itself, I looked at this question on [Ruby gems with native extensions on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450010/ruby-gem-with-native-extensions-not-working-on-aws-lambda), so am trying to package dependencies using a Lambda-like Docker image. `bundle install` fails at the `sqlite3` native extension step. When I try to install the gem by itself:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.7 gem install sqlite3
```

I see:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/runtime/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/var/lang/bin/ruby -I /var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20220430-1-n5ip9q.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
```

The [docs for the Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda) seem to indicate that sqlite-devel has been installed, though. When I ask `which -a sqlite3`, it says:

```
/usr/bin/sqlite3
/bin/sqlite3
```

When I try to build `--with-sqlite3-dir=/bin/sqlite3` or `--with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/bin/sqlite3`:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-dir=/bin/sqlite3'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/runtime/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/var/lang/bin/ruby -I /var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20220430-1-1rgbak9.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir\=/bin/sqlite3
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/var/lang/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:471:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:613:in `try_cpp'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1177:in `block in find_header'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:971:in `block in checking_for'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:970:in `checking_for'
    from /var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1176:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:68:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/runtime/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/runtime/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/runtime/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

This is where I am stuck. I note the message:

```
/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:471:in 'try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

But not sure how to make headway on that. I'm also pretty new to Docker and have been having trouble trying to read `mkmf.log`; I am getting `No such file or directory` when I try to `cat` it.

---

I found some questions/answers that indicate people have gotten SQLite working with Node and Python Lambda functions, but I don't see any discussion of Ruby functions. I also found this [layer for adding SQLite support in Python functions](https://github.com/dschep/sqlite-lambda-layer). But didn't find any such layer for Ruby.

Is a Ruby layer necessary, or is there something else I am missing? Thanks very much!